# Regex to get a string between two strings

Tags: regex

Anyone please help in getting the regex to get the string between two strings.

Full string:

```
image001.jpg (1.69 KB)SpinTel - 372464.pdf (270.90 KB)SpinTel - 372464.xlsm (113.08 KB)
```

Output expected: `SpinTel - 372464.pdf` &
`SpinTel - 372464.xlsm`

I tried the expression:

```
((?i)Spintel)(.*)(.pdf)
```

and got the one output successfully,

but when I changed the expression to

```
((?i)Spintel)(.*)(.xlsm)
```

I am getting the output as `SpinTel - 372464.pdf (270.90 KB)SpinTel - 372464.xlsm`. My expected output in this is `SpinTel - 372464.xlsm`.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: What part of your regexp do you think makes it start the match at the second `SpinTel` instead of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

To get a match only:

```
\bSpinTel\b.*?\.(?:pdf|xlsm)\b
```

- `\bSpinTel\b` Match SpinTel between word boundaries to prevent a partial match
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `\.(?:pdf|xlsm)\b` match a dot and either pfd or xlsm followed by a word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ysi0jP/1/)

If it should be followed by parenthesis, you can use a capture group for the SpinTel part, and match the parenthesis after it.

```
(\bSpinTel\b.*?\.(?:pdf|xlsm)\s+)\([^()]+\)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y65xhb/1)

Answer (score 0):

To get matches and be prepared for other file extensions.

```
((?i)Spintel - \d*.\w*)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdhJz.png)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xnscqd/1)